# Enhanced Lookup filters not returning correct values

Tags: administration, lookup

I am [setting up a suggested lookup](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm) filter on the Contacts of a New Case Entry page layout.

The problem seems to be that only results from "Recently viewed Contacts" is returned (in the screen you can see: [6]

[image]

While the actual account has 11.

- OFC - if I click on any of the accounts contacts [that are NOT shwon in the list] and I go to the Lookup filter again - I will see that last contact added to the list
- sample of doing that with a 7th contact on the account.

[image]

- I am sure that's not the way to go.

On the Search Settings - I have disabled the checkbox: Use Recently ....
[image]

But that didn't change the results.

- [Lookup search not returning results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/512/lookup-search-not-returning-results) - Did not solve my issue.
- I am using the Standard Page - not a VF one - and don't plan to create a VF look for this
- I get the same behavior from "New Case page" and "Edit Case Page"

Comment: As far as I know it's just the way SF rolls. I assume it's too expensive to run a blind search for all contacts that match the filter criteria so you need to put 2 or more characters into the search box...

Comment: But the point of the Lookup Filter is to narrow it totally. Putting characters in the search Box - (of the account name) return zero results.

Comment: try sandwiching your characters between asterisks - `*searchterm*`

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering the Account Name in the Contact Name lookup it won't return any results, unless there is a coincidental match of your search string on a Contact Name.

I agree with @eyescream that it is just how Salesforce works.  There's an [Idea: Lookup Filter Should Automatically Display Values on click of lookup button](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IEY8AAO).

When it is a required filter your search results will be limited to those that match search string and the filter.  If it is an optional filter it will initially restrict the results to those that match the search string and the filter, but will give you an opportunity to show all that match the search string, disregarding the filter.

You can add help text to the lookup window, from the filter configuration page, to explain to the user that they still need to search, so there is less of a chance for confusion. I could definitely see a scenario where the user clicks the lookup and thinks that the recently viewed list is the actual total list, if they are less familiar with Salesforce.